# Multi Regional Webmaster Tools Targeting

Tags: google-search-console, multilingual, internationalization, hreflang

We have a multi regional website which uses a two character string after the main domain to define which region's content to show e.g. `http://www.example.com/uk/` is the domain with English content specifically targeted at the UK.

There are a few pages which exist on all of the versions of the website (home page, about page, contact page). However much of the content is region specific and the structure differs somewhat depending on which region you are viewing from.

What would be the best way to implement hreflang tags based on the fact that the sites aren't set up as multi-language with the same content but are slightly different websites for each targeted region?

Also, for some reason each regional version of the website has been set up as a separate site in Webmaster Tools. We're thinking about deleting the existing entries for the website from Webmaster Tools and setting up a new single entry that covers the whole website instead of having one for each region. Could this be detrimental in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having each sub folder (/uk /de /fr ) as its own entitity in webmaster tools will allow you to target that region directly.  This tells google, when someone in the UK is searching for widgets, here is a site which is tailored for that audience.

As for Hreflang tags, only use them when the content is almost identical but the language switches.   For for example.

site.com/us/widgets.asp

site.com/uk/widgets.asp

If the above have the same content, but the currency is shown in dollars on the first but pounds on the second, you use the rel hreflang tags to let google know its the same page but alternate language.  Its really a way to prevent duplicate content errors, while also giving google insight that a translated version of the site for a specific region or language exists.   It still doesnt go as far as targeting, and right now its recommended to keep the targeting in place under webmaster tools.

To answer your question.  Webmaster tools is setup correctly.  You can use 1 google analytics, but webmaster tools should be separate.